# What causes oven program to change when oven light goes on?

Tags: oven

I have an Electrolux oven with induction burners and convection oven.  Today, I cooked a roast on 'convection/roast'.  When I opened the oven door, the program changed to 'keep warm'.  I tried the other oven programs ('regular/bake', convection/bake, etc.) and the same happened.  I've discovered that it happens whenever the oven light goes on, either by turning it on myself or by opening the oven door.  Resetting the oven at the main switch didn't help.
This is a horrendous problem as I have to reset the oven every time I open the door to check the contents.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the oven light bulb.  Does the problem go away?   (That's not a Henny Youngman "it hurts when I do this/don't do that", I have a theory and I hope to confirm it). By the way, if I am right, and your oven has a 3-wire connection, it is electrifying the frame of the oven. This can kill you. I would either affirm a 4-wire connection, or get appropriate protective gear.)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I agree with @Harper: **be careful**. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: A smart device trying to be too clever, all to common...